# Does this integral involving Bessel functions converge? or diverge?

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I cannot evaluate this integral how either:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(8xe^{-x}(I_{0}(x)-I_{1}(x))-\frac{1}{x^{3/2}(x+1)^{1/2}}\right)dx,
$$
where $I_{n}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

I expect that this value is zero because I think positive part and negative part of the integrand are cancelled out.
So, I have tried to find the value by its direction but I couldn't find well.
Moreover, I don't know even whether this integral converges or not.
(Wolfram Alpha says it diverges but I'm not sure whether it's true.)

> **My question** : Does this integral converge? or diverge? If it converges, is its value zero?

I'm glad if you give me even only hints of argument direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT 1:**

The series representation for $I_n$ is

$$I_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(k+n)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k+n}$$

**HINT 2:**

The large-argument asymptotic expansion for $I_n$ is

$$I_n(x)\sim \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\left(1-\frac{4n^2-1}{8x}+\frac{(4n^2-1)(4n^2-9)}{2!(8x)^2}-\frac{(4n^2-1)(4n^2-9)(4n^2-25)}{3!(8x)^3}+\cdots\right)$$

**HINT 3:**

Write out the first few terms of these expansions for $I_0$ and $I_1$ and determine the expansions for $I_0-I_1$.  Then, follow through with the analysis and determine whether there are convergence issues at both $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.